# Passing data component to component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I'm super new to React JS and developing small employee data view and filtering app.
Below is my working code.

**EmployeeList.js**

```
function EmployeeList(props) {
    const [mainData, setMainData] = useState(props.data);
    const [selectedDept, setSelectedDept] = useState(null);
    const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState(null);

    var departmentCodes = [...new Set(props.data.map(item => item.department))];
    departmentCodes.push("-SELECT-");
    departmentCodes.sort();

    var locationCodes = [...new Set(props.data.map(item => item.factoryLocation))];
    locationCodes.push("-SELECT-");
    locationCodes.sort();

    const handleComboDepartment = (event) => {
        setSelectedDept(event);
        filterAgain("Department", event);
    };

    const handleComboLocation = (event) => {
        setSelectedLocation(event);
        filterAgain("FactoryLocation", event);
    };

    function search(user) {
        return Object.keys(this).every((key) => user[key] === this[key]);
    }

    function filterAgain(type, data) {

        var query = {
            department: type == "Department" ? data : selectedDept,
            factoryLocation: type == "FactoryLocation" ? data : selectedLocation
        }

        let filteredQry = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(query).filter(([_, v]) => v != null && v != "-SELECT-"));

        var filteredData = props.data.filter(search, filteredQry);
        setMainData(filteredData);
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <table className={classes.table}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>Department
                                <Combobox
                                    data={departmentCodes}
                                    defaultValue={departmentCodes[0]}
                                    onChange={handleComboDepartment}
                                />
                            </th>
                            <th>Factory Location
                                <Combobox
                                    data={locationCodes}
                                    defaultValue={locationCodes[0]}
                                    onChange={handleComboLocation}
                                />
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{mainData.map((ele =>
                        <tr key={nanoid()}>
                            <td>{ele.id}</td>
                            <td>{ele.employeeName}</td>
                            <td>{ele.department}</td>
                            <td>{ele.factoryLocation}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default EmployeeList;
```

Above code is working totally fine and gives below output

[image]

when it change the combo box, then it is displaying data according to the filteration. That works totally fine.

As you can see, the combo box is repetitive (there are 2 combo boxes) and I need it to be defined a combo box as separate component, since React JS concept is to reuse components. (In my above code I repeat it twise) Then I define a new component as *CommonCombo.js* and modify the *EmployeeList.js* file.

Here is new *EmployeeList* file and *CommonCombo* file

**EmployeeList.js**

```
function EmployeeList(props) {
    const [mainData, setMainData] = useState(props.data);

    var departmentCodes = [...new Set(props.data.map(item => item.department))];
    departmentCodes.push("-SELECT-");
    departmentCodes.sort();

    var locationCodes = [...new Set(props.data.map(item => item.factoryLocation))];
    locationCodes.push("-SELECT-");
    locationCodes.sort();
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <table className={classes.table}>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Id</th>
                            <th>Employee Name</th>
                            <th>Department
                                <CommonCombo
                                    data={departmentCodes} />

                            </th>
                            <th>Factory Location
                                <CommonCombo
                                    data={locationCodes} />
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>{mainData.map((ele =>
                        <tr key={nanoid()}>
                            <td>{ele.id}</td>
                            <td>{ele.employeeName}</td>
                            <td>{ele.department}</td>
                            <td>{ele.factoryLocation}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}</tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default EmployeeList;
```

**CommonCombo.js**

```
function CommonCombo(props) {

    const handleCombo = (event) => {
        //I need to pass event to EmployeeList.js for filtering data
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <div className={classes.divWidth}>
                <Combobox                
                    data={props.data}
                    defaultValue={props.data[0]}
                    onChange={handleCombo}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CommonCombo;
```

In here (*CommonCombo*) **I need to pass the selected value to *EmployeeList.js*** file for filtering data. I stuck with it. Can any one show me a direction for doing it?

**Additional Data:**

Used combo box is *react-widgets/Combobox*.

Employee Sample Data set :

```
const EmpData = [ { "id": 5486, "employeeName": "John", "department": "HR", "factoryLocation": "Denmark" }, { "id": 5487, "employeeName": "Almeda", "department": "Admin", "factoryLocation": "Austria" }, { "id": 5488, "employeeName": "Kent", "department": "Production", "factoryLocation": "Denmark" }, { "id": 5489, "employeeName": "Peter", "department": "Production", "factoryLocation": "Austria" }, { "id": 5490, "employeeName": "Swargen", "department": "HR", "factoryLocation": "Austria" }, { "id": 5491, "employeeName": "Tim", "department": "Admin", "factoryLocation": "Austria" }, { "id": 5492, "employeeName": "Pat", "department": "HR", "factoryLocation": "Austria" }, { "id": 5492, "employeeName": "Nick", "department": "Marketing ", "factoryLocation": "Denmark" }, { "id": 5493, "employeeName": "Letrim", "department": "Production", "factoryLocation": "Austria" }, { "id": 5494, "employeeName": "Bingo", "department": "HR", "factoryLocation": "Denmark" }, { "id": 5495, "employeeName": "Sarwen", "department": "Production", "factoryLocation": "Denmark" }, ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function in your `EmployeeList` component that receives the event and then filters the data. This function has to be passed via `props` to your `CommonCombo` component. Example:

In your `EmployeeList` component:

```
function EmployeeList(props) {
  const [mainData, setMainData] = useState(props.data);

  var departmentCodes = [...new Set(props.data.map(item => item.department))];
  departmentCodes.push("-SELECT-");
  departmentCodes.sort();

  var locationCodes = [...new Set(props.data.map(item => item.factoryLocation))];
  locationCodes.push("-SELECT-");
  locationCodes.sort();

  const handleComboData = (data) => {
    // Handle your data coming from CommonCombo component
  }
  
  
  return (
      <div>
          <div>
              <table className={classes.table}>
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Employee Name</th>
                          <th>Department
                              <CommonCombo
                                  data={departmentCodes} 
                                  handleComboData={handleComboData}
                                  />

                          </th>
                          <th>Factory Location
                              <CommonCombo
                                  data={locationCodes} 
                                  handleComboData={handleComboData}
                                  />
                          </th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>{mainData.map((ele =>
                      <tr key={nanoid()}>
                          <td>{ele.id}</td>
                          <td>{ele.employeeName}</td>
                          <td>{ele.department}</td>
                          <td>{ele.factoryLocation}</td>
                      </tr>
                  ))}</tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default EmployeeList;
```

In your `CommonCombo` component:

```
function CommonCombo({ data, handleComboData }) {

  const handleCombo = (event) => {
      //I need to pass event to EmployeeList.js for filtering data
      handleComboData(event);
  };


  return (
      <div>
          <div className={classes.divWidth}>
              <Combobox                
                  data={props.data}
                  defaultValue={props.data[0]}
                  onChange={handleCombo}
              />
          </div>
      </div>
  );
}

export default CommonCombo;
```

**Note**: the other solution would be to move your change handle functions to the top level component (`EmployeeList`) and do prop drilling (passing these functions to your `CommonCombo` and then passing them to `Combobox` from that point).

Answer (score 0):

Just pass onChange prop to your CommonCombo component

```
<th>
    Department
    <CommonCombo
        data={departmentCodes} 
        onChange={handleComboDepartment}
    />
</th>
<th>
    Factory Location
    <CommonCombo
        data={locationCodes} 
        onChange={handleComboLocation}
    />
</th>

function CommonCombo(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className={classes.divWidth}>
                <Combobox                
                    data={props.data}
                    defaultValue={props.data[0]}
                    onChange={props.onChange}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```